# Why is it printing the "else"

Tags: python

Okay, so this code runs without errors, but it prints what it's only supposed to print after "else", after I enter in the input that's supposed to give me "You take a handful of blackberries".

```
if move == "up":
    forest()
    move = input("To the east there is a wooden cabin. ")
    if move == "pick blackberries":
        print("You pick a handful of blackberries.")
    if move == "take blackberries":
        print("You take a handful of blackberries")
    if move == "take blackberry branch":
        print("You scrape yourself badly on the blackberry brambles.")
    if (move == "s" or move == "south" or move == "w" or move == "west"):
        print("The blackberry bushes are impenetrable.  You scrape yourself quite badly.")
    else:
        print("I don't understand that.")
```

As in it runs like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Olga\lpthw> python functions.py
Darkness surrounds you.  You are likely to be eaten by a grue.
Above you, you see some light breaking through the rock ceiling. up
You climb out of the cave.  You are in a dense forest.
Below you is the hole in the ground you climbed out of.
To the north you see a footpath.
To the south and west there is a dense growth of trees and blackberry bushes.
To the east there is a wooden cabin. take blackberries
You take a handful of blackberries
I don't understand that.
```

It automatically prints "I don't understand that" together with "You take a handful of blackberries", even though I did not type something random.

If I run it and I type "Blah", it correctly prints "I don't understand that" however.

Also, if I get rid of everything except for "take blackberries" and the else statement that gives us "I don't understand that", so that I only have this code ...

```
if move == "up":
    forest()
    move = input("To the east there is a wooden cabin. ")
    if move == "take blackberries":
        print("You take a handful of blackberries")
    else:
        print("I don't understand that.")
```

It's actually fine, and it doesn't print "I don't understand that".

So there is something wrong with this code here I guess:

```
if move == "pick blackberries":
        print("You pick a handful of blackberries.")
    if move == "eat blackberries":
        print("They are quite tasty.")

    if move == "take blackberries":
        print("You take a handful of blackberries")
        #inventory.append("blackberries")
    if move == "take blackberry branch":
        print("You scrape yourself badly on the blackberry brambles.")
    if (move == "s" or move == "south" or move == "w" or move == "west"):
        print("The blackberry bushes are impenetrable.  You scrape yourself quite badly.")
```

What is throwing it off?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can do that simply like `if move in ['s',  'south',  'w',  'west']:`

Comment: The `else` is connected with the last `if` statement, not with every other `if` statement in the lines before. You might want to use `elif`.

Comment: Of course!  I'm very new to coding, thanks for giving me that tip

Answer (score 0):

You make a lot of If statements, but the else only applies to the last.

To make a "block" of if statements, use elif like so:

```
if move == "up":
    forest()
    move = input("To the east there is a wooden cabin. ")
    if move == "pick blackberries":
        print("You pick a handful of blackberries.")
    elif move == "take blackberries":
        print("You take a handful of blackberries")
    elif move == "take blackberry branch":
        print("You scrape yourself badly on the blackberry brambles.")
    elif (move == "s" or move == "south" or move == "w" or move == "west"):
        print("The blackberry bushes are impenetrable.  You scrape yourself quite badly.")
    else:
        print("I don't understand that."
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple if-statements that belong together (so the next one only gets evaluated if the previous one is false), you should use `elif`.

So start with an `if`, then one or multiple `elif`'s (read "el(se )if:) and finally`else:` (of not of course).

For your code:

```
if move == "up":
    forest()
    move = input("To the east there is a wooden cabin. ")
    if move == "pick blackberries":
        print("You pick a handful of blackberries.")
    elif move == "take blackberries":
        print("You take a handful of blackberries")
    elif move == "take blackberry branch":
        print("You scrape yourself badly on the blackberry brambles.")
    elif (move == "s" or move == "south" or move == "w" or move == "west"):
        print("The blackberry bushes are impenetrable.  You scrape yourself quite badly.")
    else:
        print("I don't understand that.")
```